# Android listview item, how useless xml commands impact the performances?

Tags: android, xml, performance

I populate a listview with a custom adapter.
It inflate a custom layout with many views inside it.

If I set, for example, a standard text in a TextView via xml(only to see the aspect of the view) and then I change it in code every time, this affect the performances? 
Or it's better that I remove the xml "setText" line?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking if you should have a bunch of layouts statically defined as XML or if you should create one which you dynamically adjust at run time?

Comment: No, I've already created all. In my xml textview I've leave the setText line, for example, that is useless, because I set all the correct text, color etc at runtime. But every time that I inflate the view in the listview there are 2 setText: 1 via xml(incorrect) and 1 from code(the correct one). I'm asking if this impact the performances.

Comment: Does it impact performance? In theory yes, however the majority of the time it is negligible. Depending on your number of items you could approximate the expected amount and test the behavior. In general however it should not have a noticeable impact for one item.

Comment: Yes, for one item probably not. But in a listview where I inflate 10 - 12 maybe they impact a little bit. There isn't any best practise?

Comment: Your approach is a standard practice.